# Нужна ли запятая перед «если»?

Tags: пунктуация

На фоне всего этого, если ты, будучи жителем Запада, попытаешься понять суть вопросов по этому поводу через популярные местные СМИ, вряд ли получишь ясное представление.

Спасибо.

Comment: Во фразе так много "фона всего этого", "сути", "этих поводов" и "представлений", что смысл понять невозможно. Например, что такое "суть вопросов по этому поводу"?!

Answer (score 1):

Знаки препинания расставлены верно, запятая ставится после  обстоятельственного оборота перед придаточным предложением. В то же время  **стилистически предложение некорректно**: много неясностей, повторов, содержание не выражено четко и ясно.

**В качестве варианта** (другая грамматическая форма при сохранении смысла сказанного):

На фоне всех этих фактов становится ясно: если ты, будучи жителем Запада, получаешь информацию через популярные местные СМИ, то вряд ли будешь иметь ясное представление о сути происходящих событий.

Comment: "Житель Запада" – куда как хорошо.

Comment: Говорили и говорят: "В машинах девятьсот десятого года, на тонких колесах, целыми семьями едут почтенные жители Запада". [Илья Ильф, Евгений Петров. Одноэтажная Америка (1936)]    "Выживание Запада зависит от того, подтвердят ли вновь американцы свою западную идентификацию и примут ли жители Запада свою цивилизацию как уникальную, а не универсальную... " «Отечественные записки», 2003]

Comment: Первое – это жители Дальнего Запада США. Второе, на секундочку – множественное число. По-другому сказать трудно, разве что "население Запада". У нашего же автора гораздо лучше сказать "живя на Западе". Скромненько и со вкусом! это мой девиз, наряду с "не выкаблучивайся!"

Comment: Жить на Западе и житель Запада - это не одно и то же. У жителей Запада ментальность другая, уж точно отличная от Вашей. И о стиле не забывайте: население Запада - тоже не лучший вариант,  более уместный для справочников.

Comment: А если еще проще: Житель запада, получающий информацию через популярные местные СМИ, вряд ли может иметь ясное представление о сути происходящих событий?

Comment: Да, хорошо, мне нравится, это как раз то, что называется инфостилем: короткие предложения, легко читаются и понимаются.